# Wordpress Inner pages giving 404 Error after shifted to new server

Tags: 404-error

When we made site at our server end it was working fine which was linux server.after hosting this site to AWS then it is giving me error for inner pages and if we change something it is not affecting a .htaccess file.This is giving me following error trace.

Not Found
The requested URL /Our-services was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have saved the permalinks twice.
You can save permalinks from **wp-admin => settings => permalinks**

Comment: we have tried this but not taking any effect.After setting  wp-admin => settings => permalinks=>Page Id then it works fine for us,but we can not use link like this.